# 2 keys combined in auto hotkey pressing 2 buttons

Tags: key, autohotkey

I have searched this function and used the scripts but all didn't work.

What I want is a script that if I press `a`, it does `a` and 4.

If press `d`, it does `d` and 5.

It needs to keep doing the action until I release the button.

`a` is for moving left and right is moving right in a fps games but I also wanted to do 4 and 5 at the same time while i'm holding.

Can anyone help me please?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which OS? are you talking about capturing and emulating key-presses in the background? or is it a game internal script? which language? anyway... capturing one key=press, and emulating many of the same key presses in return, will probably result in an endless loop.

Comment: AutoHotkey is a scripting/programming language and Windows only

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to add another number to a key, build up a hotkey and add the tilde (`~`) prefix:

> ~ : When the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked (hidden from the system).

```
~a::
    send 4
return

~d::
    send 5
return
```

or, shorter:

```
~a::send 4
~d::send 5
```

For more information on how to build hotkeys, available prefixes and posibilities, you might want to have a look into [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) (AHK documentation). It is pretty well written and important to understand.

---

> Thank you for the answer. Can the number 4 and 5 act like its being pressed down when im pressing a and d?
>
> Is there way to add a command this will only happen when I hold down mouse 2 and when I let go it cancels the whole command?

Assuming that with "mouse 2" you mean the right mouse button (also see [key list](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm) for other keys) (untested) :

```
sent_4_down := false
sent_5_down := false

return

~RButton & a::
    if(!sent_4_down) {
        send {4 down}
        sent_4_down := true
    }
return

~a up::
    send {4 up}
    sent_4_down := false
return

~RButton & d::
    if(!sent_5_down) {
        send {5 down}
        sent_5_down := true
    }
return

~d up::
    send {5 up}
    sent_5_down := false
return

~RButton up::
    send {4 up}
    send {5 up}
    sent_4_down := false
    sent_5_down := false
return
```

Please know that StackOverflow is there to help you with your problems, but not to code **your** scripts for you.